# How to get Mobile form id using plugin in MS CRM 2013

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I need to get the form type (whether main or mobile form) using plugin code while saving the record.Is it possible to get form id also??

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to add a custom field and populate it with formid in OnLoad script.